How to evaluate mixed model using lmer(), anova() and bootstrap when omitting random slope?
A Simulation study with the following task is given:
Do 1000 simulation runs based on simulated data from the model below to explore the following issue:
Fit a mixed model with random intercept but without random slope. How well is the coefficient of X1 (treatment effect) estimated?
For the hypothesis testing involving the mixed models, use the following choices:

t-values and critical values from t-distribution (package nlme, for factors as predictors also lmertest)
an ANOVA (use e.g. the (r)anova statement from lmertest),
do the Satterthwaite’s degrees of freedom method and the Kenward-Roger method lead to betterresults?
critical values from bootstrap simulations—reduce the number of simulation runs to get a reasonable run-time

Variables:

$y$: outcome of clinical study (effect of medication)
indiv individuals = 20
repl replicate measurements per individual taken on consecutive days after the treatment = 10
explanatory variables:
- $x_1$ ... the treatment (2 treatments) - half of the individuals receive treatment/placebo
- $x_2$ ... the time of measurement (in days, 1...10 (continuous predictor))
- $x_3$ ... indicator coding the individual

Underlying model: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \gamma_1(x_3) + \gamma_2(x_3)*x_2 + \epsilon$
Furthermore $\beta_0 = 1$, $\beta_1 = 1$, $\beta_2 = 0.5$, $\gamma_1(x_3) \sim N(0,4)$ i.i.d., $\gamma_2(x_3) \sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d., $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d.
I came up with the following code:
library(lmerTest)

Data Generation
sim.data <- function(indiv,repl,param.beta,param.gamma.1,param.gamma.2,param.eps) {
  
  indiv <- indiv          # number of individuals / people
  repl <- repl            # number of replications (= number of measurements) per individual
  
  b.0 <- param.beta[1]    # betas fixed effects
  b.1 <-  param.beta[2]
  b.2 <-  param.beta[3]
  
  x.1 <- rep(rep(0:1,each=repl),length.out=indiv*repl)  # Treatment: no,yes
  x.2 <- rep(1:10,length.out=indiv*repl)                # day of treatment per individual
  id <- rep(1:indiv,each=repl)                          # indicator coding the individual = x.3
  
  gamma.1 <- rnorm(indiv,mean=param.gamma.1[1],sd=param.gamma.1[2])
  gamma.2 <- rnorm(indiv,mean=param.gamma.2[1],sd=param.gamma.2[2])
  
  g1 <- gamma.1[id]   # intercept random effects
  g2 <- gamma.2[id]   # slope random effects
  
  e <- rnorm(length(x.1),mean=param.eps[1],sd=param.eps[2])
  
  y <- b.0 + b.1*x.1 + b.2*x.2 + g1 + g2*x.2 + e
  
  data.sim <- data.frame(x.1 = x.1,
                         x.2 = x.2,
                         x.3 = id,
                         y = y)
  
  return(data.sim)
  
}

set.seed(11525)
data <- sim.data(20,10,c(1,1,0.5),c(0,4),c(0,1),c(0,1))

true.mod <- lmer(y ~ x.1 + x.2 + (1 + x.2||x.3), REML = FALSE, data = data)    

summary(true.mod)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: y ~ x.1 + x.2 + (1 + x.2 || x.3)
   Data: data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   786.7    806.5   -387.4    774.7      194 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6798 -0.5763 -0.0162  0.5099  2.3082 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 x.3      (Intercept) 19.148   4.3758  
 x.3.1    x.2          0.624   0.7899  
 Residual              1.149   1.0720  
Number of obs: 200, groups:  x.3, 20

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   1.0620     1.4028 20.0049   0.757  0.45784   
x.1           1.0050     1.9837 19.9957   0.507  0.61797   
x.2           0.5180     0.1786 20.0132   2.900  0.00884 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr) x.1   
x.1 -0.707       
x.2 -0.015  0.000

Simulation
# set amount of simulation runs
n.sim <- 1000

# model with random intercept, but no slope
mod.mixed.no.slope <- function(y,x.1,x.2,x.3,rem.l=FALSE) {
  mod.mixed.ns <- lmerTest::lmer(y ~ x.1 + x.2 + (1|x.3),REML=rem.l)
  return(mod.mixed.ns)
}

# bootstrap function for boot()
bb <- function(data,indices) {
  s <-  data[indices, ]
  mod <- mod.mixed.no.slope(y=s$y,s$x.1,s$x.2,s$x.3)
  b.1  <- summary(mod)$coefficients[2,1]
  return(b.1)
}

beta.1.mix.ns.lmer <- numeric(length=length(n.sim))
beta.1.mix.ns.t.lmer <- numeric(length=length(n.sim))
beta.1.mix.ns.df.lmer <- numeric(length=length(n.sim))
beta.1.sign.mix.ns.lmer <- numeric(length=length(n.sim))
beta.1.sign.mix.ns.aov.satt <- numeric(length=length(n.sim))
beta.1.sign.mix.ns.aov.kr <- numeric(length=length(n.sim))
beta.1.mix.ns.sign.boot <- NULL

set.seed(1000)

for (i in 1:n.sim) {
  
    y.sim <- unlist(simulate(true.mod))
    sim.mod <- mod.mixed.no.slope(y=y.sim,data$x.1,data$x.2,data$x.3,FALSE)  # lmer-model
    
    # t-tests lmer()
    beta.1.mix.ns.lmer[i] <- summary(sim.mod)$coefficients[2,1]
beta.1.mix.ns.t.lmer[i] <- summary(sim.mod)$coefficients[2,4]
    beta.1.mix.ns.df.lmer[i] <- summary(sim.mod)$coefficients[2,3]
beta.1.sign.mix.ns.lmer[i] <- summary(sim.mod)$coefficients[2,5]
    
    # ANOVA Satterthwaite
    beta.1.sign.mix.ns.aov.satt[i] <- anova(sim.mod)[1,6]
    
    # ANOVA Kenward-Roger (only with REML)
    sim.mod2  <- mod.mixed.no.slope(y=y.sim,data$x.1,data$x.2,data$x.3,TRUE)
    beta.1.sign.mix.ns.aov.kr[i] <- if(requireNamespace("pbkrtest", quietly = TRUE)) anova(sim.mod2, ddf="Kenward-Roger")[1,6]
    
    # bootstrap critical values
    if ((i %% 20) == 0) {
      d <- data.frame(x.1 = data$x.1,x.2 = data$x.2,x.3 = data$x.3,y = y.sim)
      
      # bootstrap replicates beta* stored in beta.boot$t (unbalanced samples?)
      beta.boot <- boot(data=d,statistic=bb,R=99)
      
      # estimated bootstrap-t-values
      t <- (beta.boot$t-beta.1.mix.ns.lmer[i])/sd(beta.boot$t)
      
      # calculating quantiles of t-values-bootstrap-distribution
      quantiles <- t(quantile(t,probs=c(0.025,0.975)))
      
      # Decision significance beta (t-test critical values)
      beta.1.mix.ns.sign.boot <- c(beta.1.mix.ns.sign.boot,ifelse(beta.1.mix.ns.lmer[i] > quantiles[2] | beta.1.mix.ns.lmer[i] < quantiles[1],1,0))
    }
    
}

Findings:
# evaluation of b1 for lmer-model
mean(beta.1.mix.ns.lmer)
[1] 0.9666954

mean(beta.1.mix.ns.lmer[beta.1.sign.mix.ns.lmer<0.05])
[1] 4.617946

# power
mean(abs(beta.1.mix.ns.t.lmer)>qt(0.975,df=beta.1.mix.ns.df.lmer))
[1] 0.074

mean(beta.1.sign.mix.ns.aov.satt<0.05)
[1] 0.074

mean(beta.1.sign.mix.ns.aov.kr<0.05)
[1] 0.066

mean(beta.1.mix.ns.sign.boot)
[1] 0.4

Question:
I am very unsure about this simulation because of either a low power of the model (lmer(), anova()) or high power (bootstrap). This doesn't look right to me. I think the gap is too big, but I cannot figure out why? Maybe, the bootstrap sampling mechanism is not right, because I create unbalanced samples?
Any help is appreciated!

"... help with the code and interpretation ..." is too open-ended for our framework.  If you could identify and ask a specific question about statistics (not just about code), then that would be on topic.

Oh ok, this sentence was misleading. I don't understand the outcome why the power of the bootstrap-result is so much better than the other methods. Is this post now specific enough?
